# Upload files with Zk framework

Tags: java, gridview, file-upload, upload, zk

I need upload csv files in ZK
    this is my zul page:

```
<zk>
<window
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('UploadVM')"
    title="win"
    position="center"
    mode="overlapped"
    border="normal"
    width="300px"
    height="200px">
    <button
        label="upload"
        upload="true,maxsize=801192"
        onUpload="@command('uploadFile',upload=event)"
        autodisable="self" />

</window>
</zk>
```

And my java page:

```
public class UploadVM {
    private Media media;
    public Media getMedia(){
        return media;
    }
    @NotifyChange("media")
    @Command
    public void uploadFile(@ContextParam(ContextType.TRIGGER_EVENT) UploadEvent event) {
        media = event.getMedia();
        media.getStreamData();
    }
```

But with this simple example i have the following error:

```
Use getStringData() instead
```

And i don not know what happen.

Who can help me???

Answer (score 1):

You should know the format of the media before getting data from it. 
According to the [documentation](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/util/media/Media.html) media data can be in the `binary` or `text-based` format. To retrieve its content you should use `getByteData()` or `getStreamData()` in the former case and `getStringData()` or `getReaderData()` in the latter. For example,

```
media = event.getMedia();
if (media.isBinary()) {
    InputStream is = media.getStreamData();
} else {
    String s = media.getStringData();
}
```

Comment: And if i have a csv file, to read line per line, what i do?, because i will need getstream data or not?

Comment: @user2768380 use `media.getReaderData()` and wrap the resulted reader with `BufferedReader`

Answer (score 0):

I have a best example `dropupload` for uploading `csv` file,i thing it
 will help you for better understanding.

index.zul

```
<?page title="Auto Generated index.zul"?>
<window title="Drop here" border="normal" width="100%" height="100%"
    apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('com.demo.DropFileViewModel')">

    <dropupload maxsize="5120" detection="none"
        onUpload="@command('doUpload')">
    </dropupload>

    <button label="Download" onClick="@command('doDownload')"></button>


</window>
```

DropFileViewModel.java

```
package com.demo;

import org.zkoss.bind.BindContext;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextParam;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.ContextType;
import org.zkoss.util.media.Media;
import org.zkoss.zhtml.Filedownload;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.UploadEvent;
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;

public class DropFileViewModel {
    Media media;

    @Command
    public void doUpload(@ContextParam(ContextType.BIND_CONTEXT) BindContext ctx) {
        UploadEvent upEvent = null;
        Object objUploadEvent = ctx.getTriggerEvent();
        if (objUploadEvent != null && (objUploadEvent instanceof UploadEvent)) {
            upEvent = (UploadEvent) objUploadEvent;
        }
        if (upEvent != null) {
            media = upEvent.getMedia();
            Messagebox.show("File Uploaded: " + media.getName());

        }
    }

    @Command
    public void doDownload() {
        if (media != null)
            Filedownload.save(media);
        else
            Messagebox.show("First Drop Your File");

    }
}
```

[check here](http://corejavaexample.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-drop-your-file-using-dropupload.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is my solution for generating PDF document:

```
@Command
@NotifyChange("savePDF")
public void savePDF() throws IOException, Exception {

File f = new File("PDF_test.pdf");
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(f); 

Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

Filedownload.save(f, "application/pdf");

PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell .....
}
```